# RewriteCond [.htaccess]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to know why is this configuration returning me a 308 when requesting to /api/client via http (port 80).

Note: The device that receive the response is an ARDUINO, he doesnt handle the 3XX responses.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !='/api/client'                    # ....
    #RewriteCond expr "%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '/api/client'"    #Doesn't work
    #RewriteCond expr "%{REQUEST_URI} !~/api/"                    #Doesn't work
    #RewriteCond !%{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/client                     #Doesn't work
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/client                     #Doesn't work

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=308,L]
```

The objetive is to redirect all the HTTP request (Port 80) to HTTPS except the requests to /api/client

Comment: You evidently have "other directives" that rewrite the request (I assume to a "front-controller") - the "308 redirect" directive then redirects the _rewritten_ request (not the request that was initially requested), this should be evident by looking at the `Location` header in the redirect response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The objective is to redirect all the HTTP request (Port 80) to HTTPS except the requests to `/api/client`

Try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/api/client [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=308,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Make sure to test it after clearing old cache or from a new browser.

Comment: I love you ❤️❤️ The only thing is that the RewriteRule had a mistake. But thank you.